# HStackを使用しUIScreen上でのImageまでのwidthの値を取得したい

Tags: swift, ios, swiftui

HStackを使用し、Image(“test”)までのUIScreen上でのwidthの値を特定したいと思い、値を取得したいのですが、どの様にすればいいでしょうか。

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Apple")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width:200)
                .background(Color.yellow)
             Image(“test”)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 150)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご質問の意図が、よく汲み取れません。参考画面を図示し、”ここから”、”ここまで”とマークしていただくと、直感的に理解できると思います。お手数ですが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 確かに分かりにくくて申し訳ないです。
添付のように画面上での矢印の長さの値（X値）が知りたいと考えております。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
.bacground()にGeometryReaderで取得する様な形で値が取れました。